Tridion CMS publishing failing sites 10 DXA
When I am trying to publish any item, I am getting the below error.
Transport service failed to transport.
Unable to call OData service for discovery.SVC URL and service query "/TokenServiceCapabilities"
Can anyone please help.
Thanks

How is you CD Environment configured in Topology Manager?  Run Get-TtmCdEnvironment in a PowerShell console on the CM Server to check.

Yes, we created the toplogy using power shell commands. Now we are able to retrieve CD environments and Target types. Still publishing is failing, not able to find the root cause.

Is it possible to access the discovery svc url as returned by the Powershell command with a browser, from the server where the publisher is running?

Yes, I am able access discovery health page from publisher server

There's a similar error mentioned on the RWS Gateway in this knowledge base article. Could your issue be a problem with certificates? What do the Content Delivery logs show?

All necessary certificates are available in the server. But still I could see the below error in cd_transport logs. PKIX path building failed: sun. security. provider.certpath.suncertpathbuilderexception: unable to find valid certificate path to requested target.

Were you able to resolve this? This looks like something support could help with through RWS Gateway.
